# Ping Issue Over LAN After "Suspend" - "Destination Host Unreachable"

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ping

I am running into an issue when pinging my desktop PC from my laptop (Lenovo X1 Carbon).

- Both machines are running Ubuntu 22.04
- Both machines are connected using wifi
- **The issue starts to happen after I close my laptop lid (or click "suspend"), and then open the lid back up**

Things work fine at first and I get a response:

```
PING 192.168.1.12 (192.168.1.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=7.53 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=8.14 ms
```

Then, when I close the lid on my laptop, reopen it, and try to ping again, I get a "Destination Host Unreachable" and "No route to host" error:

```
PING 192.168.1.12 (192.168.1.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.14 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: No route to host
```

I can ping other machines on my network without an issue after opening the lid (i.e. Windows PC, TV, etc.). And I can ping my laptop from my desktop at this point too (the other direction). **When I try the ping in the other direction like this, it actually fixes the issue and my laptop can ping my desktop again afterwards!**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My ultimate goal here is to remote into my desktop PC from my laptop. Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

Laptop tcpdump before suspend (192.168.1.14):

```
jon@jon-thinkpad:~$ tcpdump -l -n -e -s0 -p -i wlp0s20f3 icmp or arp
17:27:36.154969 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:27:36.154989 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
17:28:03.297330 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:28:03.297349 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
17:28:38.418208 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:28:38.418226 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
17:28:42.722884 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.11 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:42.731943 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.10 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:42.731960 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.6 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:42.731962 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.5 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:42.731964 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.3 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:42.731966 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.2 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:42.731968 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.4 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:42.731969 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:42.731978 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
17:28:42.732012 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.8 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:42.732036 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.9 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:43.130766 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.7 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:28:43.130782 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:29:08.526129 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:29:08.526149 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
```

Laptop tcpdump after suspend:

```
jon@jon-thinkpad:~$ tcpdump -l -n -e -s0 -p -i wlp0s20f3 icmp or arp
17:31:00.481016 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:31:00.481025 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
17:31:32.636526 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:31:32.636545 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
17:32:24.775888 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.1.14, length 28
17:32:24.779337 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.1 is-at 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, length 28
17:32:32.426379 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:32:32.426401 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
17:33:22.375774 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.1.14, length 28
17:33:22.380239 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.1 is-at 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, length 28
17:33:36.549545 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:33:36.549564 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
17:33:47.618338 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.11 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.618354 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.3 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.618357 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.2 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.618358 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.14 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.618367 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.14 is-at d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, length 28
17:33:47.618401 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.8 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.618403 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.4 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.618405 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.10 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.618407 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.7 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.618436 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.6 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.618440 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.5 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.620438 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:33:47.620456 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Request who-has 192.168.1.9 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
17:34:22.791964 d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.1.14, length 28
17:34:22.795671 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > d0:ab:d5:ba:9c:da, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.1 is-at 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, length 28
```

Laptop ip before and after suspend:

```
jon@jon-thinkpad:~$ ip -ts -4 monitor neigh
[2024-03-04T17:26:59.220897] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e STALE
[2024-03-04T17:27:10.228452] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e REACHABLE
[2024-03-04T17:28:20.116782] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e STALE
[2024-03-04T17:28:34.452806] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e REACHABLE
[2024-03-04T17:29:50.368581] Deleted 192.168.1.12 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 STALE
[2024-03-04T17:29:50.368615] Deleted 224.0.0.251 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 01:00:5e:00:00:fb NOARP
[2024-03-04T17:29:50.368624] Deleted 224.0.0.22 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 01:00:5e:00:00:16 NOARP
[2024-03-04T17:29:50.368632] Deleted 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e REACHABLE
[2024-03-04T17:29:50.518990] Deleted 224.0.0.251 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 01:00:5e:00:00:fb NOARP
[2024-03-04T17:29:50.650895] Deleted 224.0.0.22 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 01:00:5e:00:00:16 NOARP
[2024-03-04T17:30:25.362439] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e REACHABLE
[2024-03-04T17:31:09.000044] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e STALE
[2024-03-04T17:31:14.888019] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e REACHABLE
[2024-03-04T17:31:55.847955] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp0s20f3 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e STALE
```

Desktop tcpdump before suspend (192.168.1.12):

```
jon@jon-bmf2:~$ tcpdump -l -n -e -s0 -p -i wlp4s0 icmp or arp
17:27:55.549791 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1 > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.5, length 28
17:27:55.549806 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:27:59.690599 48:e7:da:2a:a6:01 > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 (10:68:38:c9:0b:b3) tell 192.168.1.3, length 28
17:27:59.690609 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 48:e7:da:2a:a6:01, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:28:04.112583 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:28:04.112593 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:28:05.933158 6a:c3:74:27:91:3c > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.6, length 28
17:28:05.933174 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 6a:c3:74:27:91:3c, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:28:22.022601 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.1.12, length 28
17:28:22.025702 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.1 is-at 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, length 28
17:28:26.524497 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1 > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.5, length 28
17:28:26.524507 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:28:29.198086 48:e7:da:2a:a6:01 > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 (10:68:38:c9:0b:b3) tell 192.168.1.3, length 28
17:28:29.198095 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 48:e7:da:2a:a6:01, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:28:34.112901 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:28:34.112917 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:28:34.858630 6a:c3:74:27:91:3c > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.6, length 28
17:28:34.858640 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 6a:c3:74:27:91:3c, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
```

Desktop tcpdump after suspend:

```
jon@jon-bmf2:~$ tcpdump -l -n -e -s0 -p -i wlp4s0 icmp or arp
17:30:54.490666 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1 > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.5, length 28
17:30:54.490681 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:30:59.189303 48:e7:da:2a:a6:01 > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 (10:68:38:c9:0b:b3) tell 192.168.1.3, length 28
17:30:59.189317 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 48:e7:da:2a:a6:01, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:31:02.022600 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.1.12, length 28
17:31:02.026461 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.1 is-at 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, length 28
17:31:06.921898 6a:c3:74:27:91:3c > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.6, length 28
17:31:06.921914 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 6a:c3:74:27:91:3c, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:31:14.130287 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:31:14.130318 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:31:14.201418 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1 > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.5, length 28
17:31:14.201429 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:31:29.194457 48:e7:da:2a:a6:01 > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 (10:68:38:c9:0b:b3) tell 192.168.1.3, length 28
17:31:29.194473 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 48:e7:da:2a:a6:01, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:31:35.850567 6a:c3:74:27:91:3c > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.6, length 28
17:31:35.850583 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 6a:c3:74:27:91:3c, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:31:36.482380 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1 > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.5, length 28
17:31:36.482395 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 16:0d:59:3c:f0:f1, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
17:31:37.350589 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.1 tell 192.168.1.12, length 28
17:31:37.353640 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.1 is-at 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, length 28
17:31:44.130345 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e > 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.12 tell 192.168.1.1, length 28
17:31:44.130361 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3 > 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.12 is-at 10:68:38:c9:0b:b3, length 28
```

Desktop ip before and after suspend:

```
jon@jon-bmf2:~$ ip -ts -4 monitor neigh
[2024-03-04T17:26:12.742378] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e STALE
[2024-03-04T17:26:21.958652] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e PROBE
[2024-03-04T17:26:21.961608] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e REACHABLE
[2024-03-04T17:26:45.510632] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e STALE
[2024-03-04T17:26:51.910669] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e PROBE
[2024-03-04T17:26:51.913847] 192.168.1.1 dev wlp4s0 lladdr 9c:3d:cf:3e:c1:8e REACHABLE
...
```

Comment: Trying to pinpoint where the issue could be. Can you capture on both the desktop and the laptop? 1/ Use `tcpdump -l -n -e -s0 -p -i THEWIRELESSINTERFACE icmp or arp` (the `-e` allows to see MAC addresses, which might also matter here). You might want to obfuscate addresses, but do so only if the first hex value does not end in 2, 6, a or e (private MAC addresses), and of course keep all-ff value (broadcast). 2/ Also having at the same time (even started before the suspend) the commands `ip -ts -4 monitor neigh` could also help. 3/ Keep the "failing" ping running for more than 35s.

Comment: And check for discrepancies. sent but not received, MAC changing after suspend, altered MAC between sender or receiver (an AP could do this) etc.

Comment: Really appreciate the input. Will run these tests and report back after work.

Comment: @A.B I've updated the description to include the results. I will try to make some sense out of this before I can draw any conclusions but a few things stand out to me already. Also, IIUC these are private MAC addresses as the hex values end in 6 so I did not obfuscate. Finally, I kept the ping running for well over 35s and got the same errors after suspend. Thanks again for your help on this.

Comment: I'm sorry this leads to nothing: I can't see a single ping in the captures. You wrote you were doing pings from laptop to desktop, but they are not here. So can't even see where something actually fails. I didn't expect you to write all of it, only to give discrepancies. And also (no big deal) "the **first hex value** does not end in 2, 6, a or e" (not the last): AFAIK only 192.168.1.5 and 192.168.1.6 have a private MAC. I don't think my suggestion can't help.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm still learning basic concepts related to networking and linux so a lot of this is difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desktop PC has an MT7921 wifi card. Ubuntu prompted me for software updates today and this included [changes to the MT7921 firmware](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/linux-firmware/+changelog). After the update, I can no longer reproduce the issue. I can ping and remote into the desktop PC without any issues. Other intermittent issues that I was experiencing with wifi have also been resolved.

I'm a bit confused as to why this fixed the issue and why suspending/awaking the laptop would make a difference. But I'll take it!